# Javascript strikethrough

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been trying to figure it out but haven't got anywhere. I am new to learning Javascript so I am simply testing out how to add a item to a to do list and then when you click the li item it crosses it out.

I have been able to do all of that but where I am struggling is:

When I add a new list item, my function to strike through it doesn't work. I don't know how to solve it?

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");


function getLength() {
  return input.value.length;
};

function createElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
};


function click() {
  if (getLength() > 0) {
    createElement();
  }
};


function keyPress() {
  if (getLength() > 0 && event.which === 13) {
    createElement();
  }
};

function strikeThrough(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    item.classList.toggle("done");
  })
};

li.forEach(strikeThrough);

btn.addEventListener("click", click);
input.addEventListener("keypress", keyPress);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>WORK TO DO LIST</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>LIST OF THINGS TO COMPLETE</h1>
  <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter">
  <button id="btn">Enter</button>
  <ul>
    <li>This is a starter</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="actions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't actually get added to my array"? What have you tried to debug this?

Comment: Sorry I am new trying to learn. Essentially, the problem is, when I add a new list item, my function to strike through it doesn't work. I don't know how to solve it?

Comment: I have edited the question as I realized my error

Comment: So, you've found the error? Or what **exactly** is missing? Please explain that further by editing the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.done` class does not have any styling associated  with it, you should add some css so that the elements are getting the strike-trough;

```
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

---

After creating a new `<li>` you should call the `strikeThrough()` function again the add the eventlistener, so inside the `createElement()` function:

```
...
ul.appendChild(li);
input.value = "";
strikeThrough(li);
```

---

The `strikeTrough()` functions excepts a parameter, you should pass the elements at the foreach, instead off depending on globals;

```
// Old
li.forEach(strikeThrough);

// New
li.forEach((e) => {strikeThrough(e); });
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");


function getLength() {
  return input.value.length;
};

function createElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";
  strikeThrough(li);
};


function click() {
  if (getLength() > 0) {
    createElement();
  }
};


function keyPress() {
  if (getLength() > 0 && event.which === 13) {
    createElement();
  }
};

function strikeThrough(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    item.classList.toggle("done");
  })
};

li.forEach((e) => {strikeThrough(e); });

btn.addEventListener("click", click);
input.addEventListener("keypress", keyPress);
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>WORK TO DO LIST</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>LIST OF THINGS TO COMPLETE</h1>
  <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter">
  <button id="btn">Enter</button>
  <ul>
    <li>This is a starter</li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="actions.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer. The toggling part works in the original code, only the CSS is missing. Just inspect the list element "This is a starter", click on it, and you will see that the class was properly added

Comment: @NicoHaase I've added some more info, was still writing ;) Even tho the toggleing part worked, the function did expect a parameter.

Comment: So, `li.forEach(strikeThrough)` does not use a parameter? What else should be the input then? ;)

Comment: 0stone0 - thank you. This has worked! Sorry I should have also uploaded my CSS to my original question. Really clear explanation - helped a lot!

Comment: @NicoHaase Yea it does, but that way is not possible in the `createElement` function (right?), so I though some consistency could be helpful ;) Thx for the tip ;)